# AWS Athena - Sort by column strange behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Why some rows are ascending on year but others are descending although ASC has been specified on year?

```
select 
    e.cik,
    x."company name",
    e.year,
    e.quarter,
    e.revenue,
    e.increment,
    e.ratio
FROM 
    edgar_revenue e
    INNER JOIN xbrl as x ON 
        e.cik = x.cik
        AND e.year = x.year
        AND e.quarter = x.quarter
WHERE
    e.cik IN (SELECT cik from edgar_cik_with_revenue_growth)
    AND e.cik NOT IN (SELECT cik from edgar_cik_with_revenue_slump)
    AND e.year > 2015
ORDER BY 
    e.cik, x."company name", e.year asc, e.quarter asc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BK Technologies Corp` sorts before `BK Technologies, Inc.`.

Therefore, the first two rows (`BK Technologies Corp`) are sorted together, with the year ascending (2021, 2021)

Then there is a single row with `BK Technologies, Inc.`, so the sort order doesn't matter.

Then there are three rows with `RELM WIRELESS CORP`, which are sorted ascending by year.

Looks perfectly correct! However, it's easy to miss the difference in the company name in the 3rd line.

Comment: (Feel free to delete the question if you don't think it will help future readers.)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately cannot delete because SO does not allow once answers are provides ... "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."